# set layout background to call screen

Tags: android, events, layout, android-activity, call

[image]I have an intent that makes a call and then the call event start; I want to set background layout for that Make_Calling screen
Can anyone help me?

"Set layout for this(Image) call make screen!!"

Thanks in Advance

[image: Updated image]

Like the above(2nd) image...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much easy... In layout file there will be a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout or FrameLayout. use android:background attribute and pass drawable in it.

Comment: If Possible then reply regarding this screen image.

Comment: You want to design above kind of screen.

Comment: Updated new image . I want to set layout like this! Is it possible?

Comment: I have prepared such kind of layout for you. Please share your e-mail id with me. I will mail you the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

<s>The layout xml has a attribute background. You can set in xml or do the same in code as well. android:background="@drawable/image.png"</s>

You want to customize the default calling or incoming screen if I am right. It is not possible to customize the default screens. However, you will be able to replace the default screen with your own view. You can create an activity which calls your customised view and add the intent to the Activity in the Manifest file, similar to below

```
<activity class=".MyCustomCallActivity" android:label="@string/mycustomcall_title">
  <intent-filter>       
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER" />          
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Read [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for more details on how to handle intents

Comment: If Possible then reply regarding this screen image.

Comment: Updated new image . I want to set layout like this! Is it possible?

Comment: I have Tried that logic but it opens that view and redirected to make call activity(Default)!!!!